# Setting up varnish (or nginx) proxy within virtual machine on same box as development machine to talk to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, nginx, varnish

apologies for convoluted title.

We are wanting to set up a Varnish or NginX proxy for our production websites for load balancing and caching. However if we do this we want to replicate it into our development environment. We are a .net shop running asp.net on IIS. NginX and Varnish don't play that well with windows especially when using them this way.

I was thinking could install the proxy on a virtual machine and set up windows host to point at that VM, then have the VM proxy it back to the host environments running on different ports. However I have no idea where to begin with this.

How I imagine it would work would be something like this.

- http://www.sitename.local -> hits hosts and is directed to VM
- Varnish on VM is listening on port 80. It runs it's scripts and then sends it off to the correct spot as configured by it's rules.
- Varnish -> http://www.internal.sitename.local
- This gets sent somehow to the host windows machine

NB Mono is not an option for various business reasons.

Comment: We have nginx running on Windows and pointing to various VMs in the manner you describe above. Although we have varnish in production, those service run under Linux. Where are you having issues? One thing to note is that there seem to be issues getting nginx to only bind to specific IPs. So we couldn't get IIS and nginx running on the same box using the same ports but different IPs.

Comment: Given the mess we are replacing we will need to do some form of scripting - my reading suggested that embedded PERL module is not available on windows. Is there an alternative?

Comment: We were looking to do it the other way - NginX on the VM and IIS on the windows host.

Comment: nginx works fine in a Hyper-V VM - so your setup should be good. as for the scripting stuff, I'm afraid we only use nginx for proxying/ssl-offload - it doesn't do anything else, so I can't comment.